# light and ceiling fan wiring diagram

Tags: electrical, patio

i have a patio cover, i want to wiring 2 light and a fan with light (one light on each side of ceiling fan, so the fan will be in the center). i want two 3 ways switch to control all the lights, one switch inside the house and the second one inside the house and one switch to control the fan motor outside the house.

i have an existing power source box inside the house i want to add one 3 ways switch to that box and run a wire 14/3 to the second power box (outside the house) and connect the second 3 ways switch to turn on/off the lights and i want to connect another switch to control the ceiling fan in the same power box (outside the house).

can you give me an idea how to wire this circuit. if you can draw a diagram i will appreciate. thanks

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the existing box you wish to tap power at?

Comment: You won't be doing that with 14/3 unless you use Smart switches. Do you only want one switch that controls the fan or do you want that to be on three ways?

Comment: I count three lights ...the light in the fan, and the other two lights. Do you want all three lights to be controlled together?